# How can I discover if a property of a stored Entity is indexed or unindexed?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, datastore

I have several entities in datastore, but I don't know if some of their properties are indexed or unindexed.
How can I discover (with admin console or programatically) if a property of a stored Entity is indexed or unindexed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default each entity is indexed (unless its TextProperty or BlobProperty), you need (and should) set the property indexed property to False if you don't want it to be indexed (to improve performance and entity writing costs).

There is no indication in the admin console on if a property is indexed or not, You can try to execute "select * from  EntityType order by Property" in the GQL of the datastore views and see if it fails.

Comment: It works. An "order by" query simply skips entities which haven't have index on that property. If all entities of that Kind don't have index on the property, returns an empty result.

Comment: @shay I think you have a typo as it makes no sense. `set the property indexed property to False if you do want it to be indexed` ? Don't you mean set it to True?

Answer (score 3):

If you've been flipping between `indexed=True` and `indexed=False` on some properties over time, and have a set of entities written under both regimes, then you'll have some properties that are indexed and some that aren't. Is this the situation you're in?

If you don't have reliable history on your code, trying to determine if you're in this situation is a bit tricky, depending on how many entities you have. You can determine if you're in an inconsistent state by noting if a keys-only query on an Entity returns a different number of keys than a query that filters on the suspect property. A filter won't find unindexed properties. If you've got a lot of entities, you'll have to shard the counting somehow (to avoid timing out on a long query that returns lots of entities).

If you determine that you do have inconsistent indexing and want to repair your entities to be consistent, the usual approach is to write a [mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) that touches all of your unstable entities and issues puts on the necessary properties.

Comment: If you really want to know, say to save datastore write operations, you can also inspect the protocol buffer.  Probably not worth it unless you've got a lot of data in a mixed state.

Comment: I wanted to check if a Datanucleus JPA annotation works correctly, which is mentioned in Max Ross's [link](http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2009/11/unindexed-properties.html)blogpost[link].

Answer (score 0):

For composite indexes (i.e. the one defined in `datastore-indexes.xml` or `index.yaml`), you could use the low-level API to get the list of indexes that are present in your app's datastore.

In GAE/J, you would need to invoke [`DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().getIndexes()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#getIndexes%28%29), while in Python, the same function is provided by [`db.get_indexes()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#get_indexes).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "**Datastore Indexes**" interface, link for which is located on the left navigation menu in app engine dashboard.

There you'll see list of indexes and the specific properties on which an index has been applied.

Comment: That's not fit. Composite indexes are there only.